# How to show recursive comments based on upvotes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a comment section on my website ([privacyfirstproducts.com](https://privacyfirstproducts.com?source=stackoverflow)) and I would love to show the comments in this structure (just like hacker news):

```
comment 1 (10 upvotes)
  comment 4 (reply on comment 1, 7 upvotes)
  comment 5 (reply on comment 1, 5 upvotes)
    comment 8 (reply on comment 5, 8 upvotes)
      ...
  comment 9 (reply on comment 1, 3 upvotes)
  comment 3 (reply on comment 1, 0 upvotes)
  comment 10 (reply on comment 1, 0 upvotes)
  ...
comment 6 (2 upvotes)
  comment 7 (reply on comment 3, 2 upvotes)
comment 2 (0 upvotes)
...
```

I have this postgresql `comments`-table:

```
comment_id | original_id | upvotes | text | ...
------------------------------------------------------
         1 |        NULL |      10 | Hi.. | ...
         2 |        NULL |       0 | Je.. | ...
         3 |           1 |       0 | Di.. | ...
         4 |           1 |       7 | Si.. | ...
         5 |           1 |       5 | Op.. | ...
         6 |        NULL |       2 | Op.. | ...
         7 |           6 |       2 | Op.. | ...
         8 |           5 |       8 | Op.. | ...
         9 |           1 |       3 | Op.. | ...
        10 |           1 |       0 | Th.. | ...
```

I would love to have this as an output of postgresql:

```
comment_id | original_id | upvotes | deep | text | ...
------------------------------------------------------
         1 |        NULL |      10 |    0 | Hi.. | ...
         4 |           1 |       7 |    1 | Si.. | ...
         5 |           1 |       5 |    1 | Op.. | ...
         8 |           5 |       8 |    2 | Op.. | ...
         9 |           1 |       3 |    1 | Op.. | ...
         3 |           1 |       0 |    1 | Di.. | ...
        10 |           1 |       0 |    1 | Th.. | ...
         6 |        NULL |       2 |    0 | Op.. | ...
         7 |           6 |       2 |    1 | Op.. | ...
         2 |        NULL |       0 |    0 | Je.. | ...
```

I assume this should be done with recursion, but I can not figure out how.

Comment: So what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to solve it in JavaScript but also that didn't work: https://gist.github.com/adriaanvanrossum/4a38a4f63b446e9de5d053051e12636c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive queries are documented in the [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) section of the manual.

You start by selecting the root rows (in your case, the top level comments; the comments where `original_id IS NULL`).

The second part of a recursive query (after the `UNION` in the example below) joins the child comments to those already found. It is automatically repeated until no more rows are found. In your case the second select needs to join child comments to parents on `child.original_id = parent.comment_id`.

Finding the `depth` of each node is easy - just add 1 to the depth of the parent row when you do the second select.

The trickier part is getting the sort order you require (by votes and ID, keeping the comments grouped by parent). This can be done by accumulating the votes along with the ancestor IDs of each comment in an array (the `path` column in the following example), and then sorting the rows by the array. Note that the vote count has been negated in the example to sort higher values first. This could have been accomplished by sorting `DESC`, but then the comment IDs would have to be negated to sort earlier comments first when comments have the same number of votes.

```
WITH RECURSIVE comment_tree AS (
  -- First select performed to get top level rows
  SELECT
     comment_id,
     original_id,
     upvotes,
     text,
     0 depth,                           -- depth in the tree
     ARRAY[-upvotes, comment_id] path   -- used to sort by vote then ID
  FROM comment WHERE original_id IS NULL
  UNION
  -- Self referential select performed repeatedly until no more rows are found
  SELECT
    c.comment_id,
    c.original_id,
    c.upvotes,
    c.text,
    ct.depth + 1,
    ct.path || ARRAY[-c.upvotes, c.comment_id]
  FROM comment c
    JOIN comment_tree ct ON c.original_id = ct.comment_id
)
SELECT * FROM comment_tree ORDER BY path;
```

Comment: This is very close! Thanks for your answer. One thing that does not work yet is sorting it on upvotes. See output here: https://gist.github.com/adriaanvanrossum/ca1e6c730418362d7448056202e32be8 (I also added the queries needed to test).

Comment: I've updated the query to sort by votes first, then ID.

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript solution can be to index comments by id, iterate through them and have them point to the right parent (by using the index). Finally we can return the root nodes (with `original_id === null`) from the index:

```js
const comments = [
  { id: 1, original_id: null, upvotes: 10, text: 'Hi..' },
  { id: 2, original_id: null, upvotes: 0, text: 'Je..' },
  { id: 3, original_id: 1, upvotes: 0, text: 'Di..' },
  { id: 4, original_id: 1, upvotes: 7, text: 'Si..' },
  { id: 5, original_id: 1, upvotes: 5, text: 'Op..' },
  { id: 6, original_id: null, upvotes: 2, text: 'Op..' },
  { id: 7, original_id: 6, upvotes: 2, text: 'Op..' },
  { id: 8, original_id: 5, upvotes: 3, text: 'Op..' },
  { id: 9, original_id: 1, upvotes: 3, text: 'Op..' }
];

let index = comments.reduce((a, c) => {
  let comment = Object.assign({}, c);
  comment.children = [];
  a.set(c.id, comment);
  return a;
}, new Map());

Array.from(index.values()).forEach(comment => {
  if (comment.original_id) index.get(comment.original_id).children.push(comment)
});

const res = Array.from(index.values()).filter(c => c.original_id === null);
console.log(res);
```